# Не упомянутое — когда пишем раздельно, а когда слитно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Иногда встречается написание слитное, иногда раздельное. Когда пишем тот или иной вариант?

Answer (score 2):

*Не* с причастием?

Раздельно, когда есть зависимое слово (слова) и/или противопоставление.

У [правила про правописание "не" с причастием](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/10-klass/morfologiia-samostoiatelnye-chasti-rechi-10908/pravopisanie-prichastii-prichastnyi-oborot-11368/re-8aaf5b61-729f-47fc-b1a0-ce251173f985) есть серия маленьких тонкостей...

---

При наличии в качестве пояснительных слов наречий меры и степени ***не* с причастиями** пишется слитно.

Пример:

*совершенно невычитанная рукопись, совсем непроверенные цифры.*

Но если помимо таких наречий при причастии имеются еще другие пояснительные слова, то предпочтение отдается более общему правилу и *не* пишется раздельно.

Пример:

*совершенно не подготовленная к набору рукопись, совсем не решенная до сих пор проблема.*

Если причастие употребляется в значении прилагательного, то и при наличии пояснительных слов *не* пишется слитно.

Пример:

*по независящим от редакции обстоятельствам* (фразеологический оборот с именем прилагательным) – *рефлексы, не зависящие от воли человека* (причастный оборот).

---

*Имеют ли право на наследство другие наследники первой очереди, не упомянутые в завещании?* - зависимое слово.

*Самый главный наследник **оказался не упомянутым** в завещании,* - причастие с пояснительными словами образует часть составного сказуемого.

*Никто не может быть наследником по этому завещанию, даже если бы неупомянутый сын умирал раньше самого завещателя,* - нет ни зависимых слов, ни противопоставления.

*Первый неупомянутый факт: депутатом движет личная выгода,* - то же.

---

Правило полностью - см. **[КУЛЬТУРА ПИСЬМЕННОЙ РЕЧИ](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)**.

P. S.

> ...Правило о раздельном написании *не* с причастиями, которые имеют
>   зависимые слова, не распространяется на субстантивированные
>   (перешедшие в разряд существительных) причастия; ср.: *В классе были
>   учащиеся, не успевающие по русскому языку* (причастие). — *Количество
>   неуспевающих по русскому языку в классе было невелико* (причастие,
>   перешедшее в разряд существительных).

Comment: Галина, большое спасибо за ответ.